# Not getting expected results from plot

Tags: python, hapi

I am having trouble extracting the absorption coefficients for carbon dioxide using the hitran2016 database. I am interested in the wavelengths between ca. `1200` and `2600nm`. For methane I get expected results, based on what I have seen others get. For carbon dioxide, however, I am expecting a peak of about `0.7` at `2000nm`. However, the peak I get in my plot is of just above 0.1.

My code for methane is:

```py
from hapi import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wl_min = 1200 #[nm] wavelegnth start
wl_max = 2600 #[nm] wavelenth stop

wn_min = 1/(wl_max*10**(-7)) # Wavenumber start [cm^-1]
wn_max = 1/(wl_min*10**(-7)) # Wavenumber stop [cm^-1]

fetch('CH4',6,1,wn_min,wn_max)

describeTable('CH4')

nu,coef = absorptionCoefficient_Voigt(SourceTables='CH4',HITRAN_units=False, Diluent={'self':1})
```

And for carbon dioxide i did:

```py
fetch('CO2',2,1,wn_min,wn_max)

describeTable('CO2')

nu,coef = absorptionCoefficient_Voigt(SourceTables='CO2',HITRAN_units=False, Diluent={'self':1})
```

Not sure if I have done something differently by mistake, or if there are any bugs or misunderstandings i should fix. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The code looks correct. I do not think this is a proper board to ask why HITRAN
 data gives you more absorption than you expect.

Comment: to check for misunderstandings, you can compare your results to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339314455_Absorption_spectra_for_all_HITRAN_molecules_at_300_K_1_atm_calculated_with_RADIS_httpradisgithubio